# Modify function to take list of columns instead of just one

Tags: python

I have this function that I've created which does the following:

```py
def groupby2(df, col1, col2):
     
    return(df.groupby([col1])[col2].count().reset_index().sort_values(by=[col2], ascending=False))
```

It words great but I want to work with a multiple columns. For example if I run this:

`groupby2(df, 'Age', 'Weight')`

^ This runs fine. But this,

`groupby2(df, ['Age','Gender'], 'Weight')`

returns an error saying:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Stuck and not sure how to mend the code to accept multiple columns

Comment: `def groupby2(df, list_of_columns)`???

Comment: It's also unclear what you expect ot happen when someone passes a list of three or more columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a quick `isinstance` check and coerce the input like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

def groupby2(df, col1, col2):
    if isinstance(col1, (str, pd.Series, tuple)):
        col1 = [col1]

    return (
        df.groupby(col1)[col2].count()
        .reset_index()
        .sort_values(by=[col2], ascending=False)
    )
```

I am essentially checking to see if a single column is being passed to `col1` and coercing it to be come a list of columns. Otherwise, I assume a list is passed in and I should leave the input untouched.